# How to get links from web page using selenium

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there any way we can get the link location of webelement. I know we can get the text from webelement and also by using getAttribute("href") method we can location of link for href link. But my requirement is to get all the link. For example,

```
1.< a href="http://www.java2s.com/">Example</a> 
2. < a onclick="Test.TestFunction("9","testNumber","2");" style="cursor:pointer">This is text display on page</a>.
```

I have user below given code:

```
public void getAlllink(){
    tcount = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    System.out.println("Total Links on page :"+tcount.size());
    for(WebElement we:tcount){
    System.out.println("Link: "+str);//display element but not link.
    we.click(); //This click on link 
    System.out.println(we.getText()); //display text code that fetched by selenium and not link text
    System.out.println(we.getAttribute("href"));//display only one link http://www.java2s.com/
}
```

Is there any way to get the link location for both the element. One is simple link and another is link which is generated on call of JavaScript function.

Comment: What is your `str` variable? It isn't declared before you try to use it as far as I can see. Clicking on the link will likely change the content of the browser, hence the `.getText()` and '.getAttribute()` methods are going to fail unless you click AFTER you get those details.

Comment: Thanks Mark for you reply. Yes you are right when click function is called it change the content fo browser and hence script fails. str is String variable which that str=we.toString(); but it display text code which is fetched by selenium

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Java2sAllLinksCapture {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.java2s.com/");
    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    System.out.println(links.size());
    for(int i=0;i<links.size();i++){
        //print the link text
        System.out.println(links.get(i).getText());
        //Print the href's
        System.out.println(links.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: If u r satisfied with the above code,pls select the upper arrow "This answer is useful"

Comment: Sorry.Why i am getting -1 for this answer .

Comment: Hi Karim Narsindani, i have a quick question that is i think u want first open the parent browser and get the href link and then click the child links one by one in the parent page, then open the new page means child page then go back to parent page and click on next link then open the child page get the url and title then go back to parent page like that?? I think u try to get the all parent and child hrefs. If this is your question? If yes i have answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to click on the link to execute the javascript function that will in turn return a link that will be used as the destination. Clicking on the link will take you to the destination page, which makes the previous webElements unavailable, therefore the link cannot be retrieved. Without clicking on the link, javascript function will not execute and generate the link.

Comment: Thanks Sarah for your valued inputs. The reason behind this question, is I am developing tool to validate links using selenium for my company web application. However, I am able to validate links which are with href link 'www.test.test/test1' but we also have some link like href "#" and with javascript function, when user click on button system generate the link. Is there any way to generate such link without loosing existing page. Or can we get the javascript function name than I think using selenium we can execute required javascript.